# htaccess for multiple PHP files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm being stuck setting up my htaccess properly. Currently I have the following situation:

```
1). mydomain.com/my/details.php?pid=top-news-around

2). mydomain.com/my/toplinks/link.php?id=top-news-around
```

stated .htaccess works fine with **mydomain.com/details.php?pid=1111**, but does not work for **mydomain.com/toplinks/link.php?id=top-news-around**. please let me know whats wrong with .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ my/details.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ my/details.php?pid=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ my/toplinks/link.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ my/toplinks/link.php?id=$1
```

thanks for your help

Comment: question was not explain properly

Comment: yes it was explained properly!

Comment: What sort of URLs do you want to go to details.php and what sort to link.php?  Your htaccess is sending everything to details.php _because your first regular expression tells it to_.

Comment: @daiscog. actually there is button in detail.php which should goto mydomain.com/toplinks/link.php?id=top-news-around

Comment: You misunderstand me.  Can you give me a real example of a URL _path_ that is supposed to be rewritten to `my/toplinks/link.php?id=$1`?

Answer (score 1):

again you conditions are the same. change them to access different files. like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^details/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ my/details.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^details/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ my/details.php?pid=$1

RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ my/toplinks/link.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ my/toplinks/link.php?id=$1
```

calls like `mydomain.com/details/top-news-around` and `mydomain.com/link/top-news-around`

Comment: then your paths are wrong! (my/toplinks/link.php and/or my/details.php) check them...

Comment: its works fine with (RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ my/details.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ my/details.php?pid=$1) but when i write following code its returning error...RewriteRule ^details/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ my/details.php?pid=$1
RewriteRule ^details/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ my/details.php?pid=$1

Comment: Andreas has given an _example_ solution (hence "like:").  But without knowing what your URLs that are supposed to go to each script look like (and crucially _how they are different_) nobody can give you a precise solution.  All we can say is that you need to make the regular expressions more specific.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the problem, let's take a look at what Apache is doing when a request hits the server.

1. A browser makes a request for `http://mydomain.com/an/example/page`.  To do this, it connects using HTTP to the server at mydomain.com and sends `GET /an/example/page` request (along with all the usual HTTP request headers).  `/an/example/page` is the *request path*.
2. The web server (Apache) now has to decide which file to use to serve the request.  There's a lot that goes on here, but eventually it will come to read the `.htaccess` files, starting with the one in the document root.
3. Apache gets to the line that says `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ my/details.php?pid=$1` and checks the request path against the given regular expression.  The regex will match any string that is entirely made up of one or more of the characters in the class `[a-zA-Z0-9-/]`.  `an/example/page` matches the regex, so Apache rewrites the *relative* URL to `my/details.php?pid=an/example/page`.
4. Because you have not set the `[L]` flag, Apache will continue to try to match the *new* URL against the other rules.  The new URL contains a dot, so it does not match.  The file `my/details.php` is called, with the query string `pid=an/example/page` and the output from running that script is returned to the browser.

Now, because the first regex in your .htaccess is so broad, it will match pretty much ***any*** requested URL that does not have a dot.  This means that *every* request you make without a dot is being rewritten by the first rule.  Note that even ones like `/an/example/page/` (note the trailing slash) will get rewritten to `my/details.php?pid=an/example/page/` (*including* the trailing slash) because it matches the first regex before Apache even looks at the second one (which it appears has been designed to remove the trailing slash - but it will not because it will never get the chance to be matched against the URL).

I hope this clears up why your .htaccess file isn't working as you expect it to.  In order to get it to work as desired, you need to use more specific pattern matching, as others have shown examples of.  But without knowing what all your URLs look like and where you want them all to go, nobody is going to be able to give you the correct answer.